# Loading data in Winter '16

Tags: data-loader, winter16

There is a [known bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jZZhAAM) where the latest data loader for Mac is not working.

The workaround states:

> In the meantime, users may use the older version of Data Loader for
>   Mac or Workbench.

I assume this refers to [Lexi Loader v. 30](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/lexiloader/). I have used Workbench and LexiLoader v.30 successfully before Winter '16, but now they can't seem to connect to API 35. With LexiLoader I get:

```
Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0
```

and Workbench keeps giving:

```
An error has occurred and you have been logged out:
Your Salesforce session is invalid or has expired. Please login again.
```

Is there any known version that works with the Winter '16 API and where can I get hold of it?

Comment: Can you use the native Import tools?  The Data Import application from Setup has made significant changes from the last version.  Might help while you wait for an answer.

Comment: I'm finding the Data Export tool very limited. I exported one data set and then was unable to do another "now" export even three days later. Not a working workaround for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: While connecting to Workbench which API version you are using? Can you try logging in workbench with lower version. It should work. I'm able to login in my Developer Environment.

Answer (score 5):

Here are all the versions of LexiLoader:

http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/lexiloader/

I have been using v25 without any issues in Winter 16...Not sure if newer versions work

I believe this is a direct answer to your question. Please let us know if this works for you

Comment: I get the same `Failed to send request to https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/25.0` error message with v25

Comment: Hmm...It is working for me when connecting to a winter 16 org both in prod and sandbox

Comment: This didn't work for me, but since by the upvotes it looks like it has helped at least 5 folk in the community, the bounty goes to you. Thanks for the pointer Eric!

Comment: @JannieT - Sorry it did not work for you. But knowing that it DOES work for others gives you a point to start to find the issue. I would suggest try opening an new DE org, then use Lexi Loader to access it. Try from a different computer as well, maybe you are still running the latest mac executable instead of the v25 one and the logos are the exact same....Just some thoughts. It could be an issue with your pod, org, or computer, all of which you could remove from the equation and test...

Answer (score 3):

Jamie, you might want to consider using [JitterBit's native Mac application.](http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/) I have just used it fine to upsert a CSV of account's on Winter 16 without any problems. (It is also free!)

Comment: Looks promising, but I had trouble getting it installed on El Capitan. Maybe it is because it is trying to install it's own bundled version of the Java runtime. I sent a bug report to Apple FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the following URL : https://workbench.developerforce.com to Login to workbench and My Dev org is on Winter'16. I tried using the Apex Data Loader as well but all are working fine without any issue. It would be great if you can clear your browser cache and then try to login to workbench using the API Version 35.0.

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: I could log in with a workbench using API 34, so +1, but it doesn't provide data export like I need.

Comment: If you want to Export the data  from your org, you have following options: 1. Data Export in salesforce which can bt search by Setup--->> Data management --->> Data Export --->> Choose the Object and export it.            2. You can use the Data Loader to export the data . Steps: Setup ---->>Data management --->> Data Loader --->> Download it and Run  -->> It will ask for Username ,Password.       Enter the Username and Password = password + security Token . Steps to find the Security Token Setup --->> Personal Profile Setting -->>> Reset My Security Token. Please mark this as best answer.

Comment: You can also you the following article if you want only to use workbench:  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205697&language=en_US      or You can use : https://www.aside.io/  Login to sandbox or production --->>> Choose the "<" Sign on the top Right Corner and choose Data. Enter the SOQL Query and Export it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering other options that data loader and have limited data to import export (< 50k per month )then you can use free version of [dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io). its very user friendly and have great features

Answer (score 0):

> and Workbench keeps giving:
>   An error has occurred and you have been logged out: Your Salesforce
>   session is invalid or has expired. Please login again.

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by going to Setup/Session Settings and unchecking "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated". If that doesn't work, you might want to also try unchecking "Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used".

[I found this suggestion here.](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/issues/744)